# How to skip array if empty in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, concatenation

I create an array from a json url through json_decode. I do some stuff with the various nested arrays. I also want to do some stuff with the data from all the nested arrays. Therefore I thought it would be handy to concat the arrays into one again (but now not nested) and loop through that as well. The concat works perfect. But when I try to sort the new array on a key/value, it errors out and I know why. One or more of the arrays that is sometimes empty (dynamic data source). Thus the array is for example;

```
"various":null
```

This is how I create the various vars for my script.

```
var data_hazards = data_all['alerts'][0]['hazards'];
var data_various = data_all['alerts'][0]['various'];
var data_standstill = data_all['alerts'][0]['standstill'];
var data_roadclosed = data_all['alerts'][0]['roadclosed'];
var data_accidents = data_all['alerts'][0]['accidents'];
var data_police = data_all['alerts'][0]['police'];
var data_construction = data_all['alerts'][0]['constructions'];
var data_jams = data_all['alerts'][0]['jams'];
//Concat the above arrays
var data_total = data_hazards.concat(data_various).concat(data_standstill).concat(data_roadclosed).concat(data_accidents).concat(data_police).concat(data_construction).concat(data_jams);
```

Now I am wondering how to skip an array in the concat() when it is empty.

Does anybody have an idea?

Love to hear from you.

Regards,

Ruud

Comment: You can check if it is empty before concatenating it, using `if`

Comment: how about `if (someArray.length !== 0)`?

Comment: Is the array empty (a.k.a no elements in it) or is it `null` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a default empty array for concatination all arrays. You do not need to chain [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), because you could use more arrays as parameters.

```
var data_total = [].concat(
        data_hazards || [],
        data_various || [],
        data_standstill || [],
        data_roadclosed || [],
        data_accidents || [],
        data_police || [],
        data_construction || [],
        data_jams || []
    );
```

An other solution could be an array with the values.

```
var data_total = [
        data_hazards, data_various, data_standstill, data_roadclosed, data_accidents, data_police, data_construction, data_jams
    ].reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a || []), []);
```

Test cases for empty array or falsy values with default array:

```js
// concat empty array to an empty array
console.log([].concat([]));         // []

// use default array if falsy value
console.log([].concat(null || [])); // []

// concat a value to an empty array
console.log([].concat(['foo']));    // ['foo']
```

Comment: This worked perfect! Thanks! Didn't have time to implement the solution earlier. Sorry for the late response. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

There's an obvious repeated pattern in your code, and therefore a lot of duplication. I suggest the following to fix that and solve your problem at the same time:

```
const data_total =
  ['hazards', 'various', 'standstill', ...]
    .map(key => data_all['alerts'][0][key]) // retrieve data for each key
    .filter(data => data != null) // ignore those that are null
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []); // concat them all together
```